# Expression Trees and PropertyDescriptor

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees, typedescriptor, propertydescriptor

Is there any clean way to get a `PropertyDescriptor` from an expression tree?

I currently have `PropertyInfo` but I ideally want `PropertyDescriptor`, my code:

```
var prop = 
    (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)
        ((MemberExpression)
            ((Expression<Func<TestClass, long>>)
                (p => p.ID)).Body).Member;
```

My need for PropertyDescriptor is because I need to use:

```
if (prop.CanResetValue(this))
{
    prop.ResetValue(this);
}
else
{
    prop.SetValue(this, null);
}
```

I cannot use `PropertyInfo.SetValue(this, null, null)` as it does not suit my needs, as I need to reset to the default value specified by the `DefaultValueAttribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this? (Untested, sorry!)

```
var prop = /* same as in your example above */

var descriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
var descriptor = descriptors[prop.Name];

if (descriptor.CanResetValue(this))
{
    descriptor.ResetValue(this);
}
else
{
    descriptor.SetValue(this, null);
}
```

Comment: nice and simple, for some reason intellisense was telling me that `PropertyDescriptorCollection` only works with an `int` index not `string`, resetting VS2010 seems to have fixed that.